# Flutter - Call animate function of a child from parent, or from another child class

Tags: animation, callback, flutter

I have two animating menus.   dropDownMenu is working fine, and I can set onPress events from this child to perform functions in the parent class using callbacks, for example:

```
class dropDownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() onPressed;
  final String tooltip;
  final IconData icon;
  final _callback;

  dropDownMenu({Key key, this.onPressed, this.tooltip, this.icon, @required void singlePlayerCallbacks(String callBackType) }  ):
      _callback = singlePlayerCallbacks, super(key: key);

  @override
  _dropDownMenuState createState() => _dropDownMenuState();
}

 class _dropDownMenuState extends State<dropDownMenu>
   with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Stack(
       children: <Widget> [
         Column(
          Container(
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.0,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              onPressed:  isOpened == true? (){
                widget?._callback('dice');
              } : () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And then in the parent class:

```
class SinglePlayerMode extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SinglePlayerModeParentState createState() => SinglePlayerModeParentState();
}

class SinglePlayerModeParentState extends State<SinglePlayerMode> {

callBacks(String callBackType) {
  switch(callBackType) {
    case 'dice':
    {
        diceVisible = !diceVisible;
        int rng = new Random().nextInt(19) + 1;
        setState(() {
          diceResult = rng;
        });
      }
    }
  break;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: dropDownMenu(
            singlePlayerCallbacks: callBacks,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  }
```

As a quick example, and this works perfectly fine.

What I need to do next is have another animated menu, called styleMenu, that animates when a button from dropDownMenu is pressed.   This is where I am running into massive hurdles.  I honestly don't mind HOW I get this done, I just need to get it done.   This is what I am trying currently, without any success:

In dropDownMenu I have another button with a callback to the parent first:

```
Container(
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: 0.0,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: null,
      onPressed:  isOpened == true? (){
        widget?._callback('theme');
      } : () {},
    ),
  ),
),
```

Which triggers the callback function of the parent again, with a different switch case:

```
callBacks(String callBackType) {
  case 'theme':
    {
      styleMenuState().animate();
    }
  break;
```

I obviously can't do this because it tells me that I am trying to animate a null object.  Like I somehow have to instantiate styleMenu before I can call this function from here, but I don't know how to do this or even if it is possible.

My styleMenu class (extract):

```
class styleMenu extends StatefulWidget {
 final Function() onPressed;
 final String tooltip;
 final IconData icon;
 final _callback;
 final VoidCallback animate;

 styleMenu({this.onPressed, this.tooltip, this.animate, this.icon, @required void singlePlayerCallbacks(String callBackType) }  ):
       _callback = singlePlayerCallbacks;

 @override
 styleMenuState createState() => styleMenuState();
}


class styleMenuState extends State<styleMenu>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isOpened = false;
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<Color> _buttonColor;
  Animation<double> _animateIcon;
  Animation<double> _translateButton;
  Curve _curve = Curves.easeOut;
  double _fabHeight = 52.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    animationController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    _animateIcon =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(animationController);
    _buttonColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.blue,
      end: Colors.red,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        1.0,
        curve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ));
    _translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: _fabHeight,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        1.0,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  animate() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      styleMenuState().animationController.forward();
    } else {
      styleMenuState().animationController.reverse();
    }
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget> [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    0,
                    _translateButton.value,
                    0,
                  ),
                  child: blueTheme(),
                ),
               Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    0,
                   _translateButton.value * 2,
                    0,
                  ),
                  child: greenTheme(),
                ),
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    0,
                    _translateButton.value * 3,
                    0,
                  ),
                  child: redTheme(),
                ),
            blackTheme(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
```

Again, I just need to be able to trigger the animate function from the styleMenu to pop this menu out by pressing a button inside the dropDownMenu and I just can't get my head around how to do this!  I am sure there must be a simple way, but I am unable to find anything online.

Any pros out there?

Comment: Could you post your sample code as a whole in a runnable state? It's easier for people and quicker for people to help.

Comment: There is too much code to paste this in a runnable state.   If anyone even knows the base theory of what is required here, that would be an amazing place to start.   I am looking down the StreamBuilder or ListenableBuilder paths, is this the right direction?   If we have a direction we can flesh this out more.   This forum doesn't let me copy and paste 18 pages of code, I have included everything that is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I was just working on a similar problem. Using Streams, Provider with ChangeNotifiers, or inherited widgets are viable options. If you do want to simply trigger the child widget animations on setState called from the parent you can do that by using the didUpdateWidget in the child widget as shown below

```
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ImageHeartAnimation oldWidget) {
    _controller.forward().orCancel;
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```